# How to solve this quadratic program using the penalty method?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

example:
$$\min\frac{1}{2}((x_1-3)^2+(x_2-2)^2)$$
s.t.$$-x_1+x_2{\le}0$$
$$x_1+x_2{\le}1$$
$$-x_2{\le}0$$
and we start with $~x^0=[3,2]^T~$ its violate the condition  :
$$q(x,c)=\frac{1}{2}((x_1-3)^2+(x_2-2)^2)+\frac{c}{2}((x_1+x_2-1)^2)$$
and what is next?

calculate $~x_1~$and$~x_2~$ with BFGS, newtons method,....

$\nabla_x q(x,c)=0~$,$~c=~$ a very large number starting with $~10,100,1000,\cdots~$ until the solution has very small difference?

Comment: Do you know how the [penalty method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method) works? After you iterate from the initial point, you come to the next point and must rebuild $q(x,c)$ for the next step depending on what constraint are violated now as well as increase $c$. Not clear what $q(x,c)=0$ is supposed to mean.

Comment: let me repeat what I understand form your statment
we use 3,2 for the first iteration any violate constraint will become nonzero
after that we calculate the result with c =10 and find $x_1$,$x_2$ with gradient=0
and we get new $x_1$,$x_2$ for 2nd iteration
I follow the step from here https://youtu.be/icKd4QLNdsE?t=1063
but I am not sure what is it means gradeint=0 (is it just like find the maximum with deterative?)
NLP means non linear programming

Comment: "Nonlinear" is too broad. This is a (convex) quadratic program!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my comments on the method.

1. The [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icKd4QLNdsE&feature=youtu.be&t=1063) you mentioned does not describe the example completely. Formally, the $q$-function there is incorrect in the sense that $\nabla_x q(x,c)=0$ does not solve the problem in general. What it does solve is the *first iteration minimization* only starting from the given initial point. The complete auxiliary function should look as e.g.
   \begin{align}
   q(x,c)=&\frac{1}{2}((x_1-3)^2+(x_2-2)^2)+\\
   &+\frac{c}{2}(\max\{0,-x_1+x_2\}^2+\max\{0,x_1+x_2-1\}^2+\max\{0,-x_2\}^2).
   \end{align}
   For the given initial point $x^0$ it takes the form as you stated, but at other points of the plane it is (or may be) different.
2. A solution to $\nabla_x q(x,c)=0$ is the global minimizer in the problem 
   $$
   \min_x q(x,c)
   $$
   because the function $q(x,c)$ is *convex* in $x$. It is the known theoretical fact for convex functions. It gives an analytical solution (for lecture's sake). In practice, this step is replaced by Newton/quasi-Newton methods. Moreover, it is often enough to take one iteration of the chosen numerical method to get the next iteration, since it is only one step of the penalty method and to make the exact minimization is too expensive and unnecessary.

Normally the method works like this: for an iteration point $x^k$ do the following

1. Take $x^k$ and the penalty level $c_k$ and calculate $q_k(x,c_k)$ *above* for $x$ nearby $x^k$. Depending on where $x^k$ is (what constraints are violated) $\max$-penalties become different, some will disappear if $\max=0$ (i.e. the corresponding constraint is satisfied at $x^k$).
2. Calculate the next iteration $x^{k+1}$ by taking one step of a Newton-related method for $q_k(x,c^k)$, starting from $x^k$.
3. If $|x^{k+1}-x^k|$ is small enough then STOP, otherwise update $x^k=x^{k+1}$, $c^k=10*c^k$ and continue with the Step 1.

Comment: Oh I calculate new ${x_1,x_2}$ with partial derivative
u suggest do it with Newton method or other method is it a must?

Comment: @LinearAlgebrafans Well, in the example, solving $\nabla_x q(x,c)=0$ is rather easy (a linear equation in $x$), but, in general, the equation can be really hard up to impossible to solve, so to do a Newton kind of step is often the only option.

Answer (score -1):

Show that $$\frac{1}{2}((x_1-3)^2+(x_2-2)^2)\geq 4$$ the equal sign holds if $x_1=1,x_2=0$

Comment: It is *not* the penalty method.

Comment: where's 4 come form lol